# Understanding SQLite Thread Pooling Behavior in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

```
list_of_some_class_dictionaries = [{'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}, ...]
engine.execute(SomeClass.__table__.insert(), list_of_some_class_dictionaries)
```

This breaks using `NullPool` with a SQLite file database (the default); it throws a `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) database is locked` error. However it works with a `SingletonThreadPool` with either a SQLite file database or a SQLite in memory database.

```
list_of_objects = [SomeClass(foo=foo, bar=bar), ...]
for object in list_of_objects :
    session.add(object)
```

This code utilizing the ORM layer works fine with the `SingletonThreadPool` on a SQLite in memory database, and with `NullPool` on a SQLite file database. However, it's significantly slower.

I'm using SQLAlchemy version 0.8.3, so the default for a SQLite file based database is `NullPool`, and `SingletonThreadPool` for a SQLite in memory database.
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#pysqlite-threading-pooling

My question is why exactly does the first snippet break using `NullPool` with a SQLite file database? I'd like to use this snippet due to it being faster (~1.5 times the speed of the second snippet).

**EDIT :**

```
list_of_some_class_dictionaries = [{'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}, ...]
session.execute(SomeClass.__table__.insert(), list_of_some_class_dictionaries)
```

Calling execute off of the session object as opposed to the engine object, seems to mitigate the issue. I think that calling `engine.execute` may have attempted to open up another connection while the database was still locked to the session. However, I'm not familiar enough with SQLAlchemy to be sure.

Comment: I think you figured it out with the edit. The engine would not hand out the connection it gave to the session a second time thus causing the error. Either stay on the session or close the session.